# Lets Encrypt certificate issue with Kestrel

Tags: c#, lets-encrypt, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to use a certificate from Lets Encrypt in Kestrel under a net core 6 project. When running my project I get an error that the certificate is expired. When you look at the details you see that the trust path is Cert -> R3 (Expires: September 29, 2021) -> DST Root CA X3 (Expires: September 30, 2021). If I start Nginx I get the following Cert -> R3 (Expires: September 15, 2025) -> ISRG Root X1 (Expires: June 4, 2035).

Has anyone seen something similar?